# C++ managing the dynamic allocation of your objects

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to implement my own class Alloc which will help in the dynamic allocation of objects..

I want to keep track of the number of allocated objects in my program. So, each time a new instance of an object is allocated, the counter increments by one and decrements when an object is destroyed. When my program shuts down, if the counter is not at zero, the object prints an error message to the screen and has the program hang until the user hits enter..

This is what I have so far.. I hope you guys can help me to implement this..

```
class Alloc{
static int counter;
public:
Alloc(){ counter++; };
Alloc(int *d, static int size, const Alloc& c){

    d=(int *) malloc(size*sizeof(int));;
    //d=new int[size];
    Alloc *my_alloc;
    //my_alloc = new Alloc[size];                //note that the type is a Myclass pointer
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        my_alloc[i] = new Alloc[size];
    }
    //for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
    //    d[i]=c.d[i];
    //}
}
~Alloc(){ counter--; }
};
```

I know a lot is missing so, I will appreciate help and fixing mistakes too.. 
Thanks!!!

Comment: Sounds like something Valgrind can already do.

Comment: This code makes no sense at all. Maybe you should post how you intend to *use* this class, because it's not at all clear what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: This code will not compile. 

0) We are in a constructor of a calss called Alloc which accepts a static int size (this should not compile )  

1) d is created as an array of int c style  

2) d is overwritten as an array of int c++ style the original content of d is leaked  

3) we create a new array of Alloc objects c++ style  

4) in a loop over the Alloc objects we try to replace each actual Alloc object with a pointer to an array of Alloc objects (this should not compile)  

Finally we leave the function leaking d and my_alloc

Answer (score 2):

```
d=(int *) malloc(size*sizeof(int));;
d=new int[size];
```

The second line here is overwriting the `d` pointer with a second allocation, so the memory allocated by `malloc` is being lost!

If you really want to do it this way you need to use [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax), i.e. something like

```
d=(int *) malloc(size*sizeof(int));;
e=new (d) int[size];
```

though the details are quite tricky to get right.

---

To just count the number of objects in your programme though, there is a much easier option. Implement a templated "mixin" which contains a static counter for each type. Something like

```
    template <typename T>
    struct countable
    {
        countable() { _count++; }
        countable(const countable&) { _count++; }
        ~countable() { _count--; }
        static int get_count() { return _count; }
    private:
        static int _count;
    };
```

and then having your objects inherit from this, as in

```
    class MyClass : countable<MyClass>
    {
        // whatever
    };
```

It's simple, and easy to turn into a no-op for release builds.

Answer (score 2):

the track of number of instances of class say Alloc can also be kept as

```
class Alloc
{
    Public:
    static int Coounter; // object counter

//  Constructor

    Alloc(){
    Counter++;}

//  Destructor

    ~Alloc()
    {
    Counter--;
    }


};
```

Simple, easy to use and maintainable